# lumen and mongodb and aggregate

Tags: mongodb, lumen

I want to use aggregate for group but how do I use laravel-mongodb like this:

```
// col
    $pipeline =  $this->getCollection() -> createPipeline();
    $pMatchArr = array(
            'ij_statistics_time' => array(
                '$gte'  => $_intStartTime,
                '$lte'  => $_intEndTime
            )
    );
    if(!empty($_intUid)){
        $pMatchArr['ij_uid'] = $_intUid;
    }
    $pipeline->match($pMatchArr);
    // get date
    $pipeline = $pipeline->group(
        array(
            '_id'=>'$ij_uid',
            'level_one_count'=>array( '$sum'=>'$ij_level_one_new_num' ),
            'level_two_count'=>array( '$sum'=>'$ij_level_two_new_num' ),
            'level_three_count'=>array( '$sum'=>'$ij_level_three_new_num' ),
            'level_four_count'=>array( '$sum'=>'$ij_level_four_new_num' ),
            'level_five_count'=>array( '$sum'=>'$ij_level_five_new_num' ),
            'level_six_count'=>array( '$sum'=>'$ij_level_six_new_num' ),
            'level_seven_count'=>array( '$sum'=>'$ij_level_seven_new_num' ),
            'level_eight_count'=>array( '$sum'=>'$ij_level_eight_new_num' ),
            'level_nine_count'=>array( '$sum'=>'$ij_level_nine_new_num' ),
            'level_ten_count'=>array( '$sum'=>'$ij_level_ten_new_num' ),
        )
    );
    $pipeArr = $pipeline->aggregate();
    return $pipeArr;
```

It looks like it does not work

```
$pipeArr = $cursor->groupBy( 'ij_uid' )
        ->aggregate( 'sum' , $fileds)
        ->get( $fileds );
    return $pipeArr;
```

I'm using lumen 5.2 and jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

I use the following methods to solve the problem, can be used in the orm native statements

```
    $pipeArr = self::raw( function($collection) use ($match ) {
        return $collection->aggregate([
            ['$match' => $match],
            [
                '$group' => [
                    '_id' => '$ij_uid',
                    'level_one_count'       => [ '$sum' => '$ij_level_one_new_num'],
                    'level_two_count'       => [ '$sum' => '$ij_level_two_new_num'],
                    'level_three_count'     => [ '$sum' => '$ij_level_three_new_num'],
                    'level_four_count'      => [ '$sum' => '$ij_level_four_new_num' ],
                    'level_five_count'      => [ '$sum' => '$ij_level_five_new_num' ],
                    'level_six_count'       => [ '$sum' => '$ij_level_six_new_num' ],
                    'level_seven_count'     => [ '$sum' => '$ij_level_seven_new_num' ],
                    'level_eight_count'     => [ '$sum' => '$ij_level_eight_new_num' ],
                    'level_nine_count'      => [ '$sum' => '$ij_level_nine_new_num' ],
                    'level_ten_count'       => [ '$sum' => '$ij_level_ten_new_num' ]
                ]
            ],
            ['$sort' => ['ij_uid' => 1]],
        ]);
    });
    return $pipeArr;
```